# Facebook iFrame Title

Tags: facebook, iframe, accessibility, title, facebook-login

I currently have a project being reviewed by our accessibility team.  Mostly everything passed with the exception of a Facebook iFrame.  We need to set a title on the iFrame but I haven't been able to find any properties to set a title nor have I found any docmentation on how to give it an iFrame.  How does one assign or set the attribute on a Facebook login iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

It should be done on your end? `<iframe src="..." title="login to our site using Facebook"></iframe>`

Comment: He may be using one of the JavaScript widgets that create an iframe.

Comment: The javascript creates the iframes.  I haven't found any properties to set the value but didn't know if there was something I was missing.  It is being used to login using facebook.